# Unable to validate flask wtf from

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I am not able to validate my flask wtf form.

```
@app.route('/rss_feed',methods=['POST'])
def rss_feed():
    form = rss_form(request.form)
    from_year = int(request.form['from_year'])
    to_year = int(request.form['to_year'])
    res= ''
    print(from_year)
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
        return jsonify({'test': request.form})
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/prm/projects/environments/sec_download/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2328, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/prm/projects/environments/sec_download/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2314, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/home/prm/projects/environments/sec_download/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1760, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/prm/projects/environments/sec_download/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 36, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/prm/projects/environments/sec_download/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2311, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/prm/projects/environments/sec_download/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1834, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/prm/projects/environments/sec_download/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1737, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/prm/projects/environments/sec_download/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 36, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/prm/projects/environments/sec_download/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1832, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/prm/projects/environments/sec_download/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1818, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/prm/projects/quantum-xbrl-processor/focusfi_ui.py", line 46, in rss_feed
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
  File "/home/prm/projects/environments/sec_download/lib/python3.5/site-packages/wtforms/form.py", line 310, in validate
    return super(Form, self).validate(extra)
  File "/home/prm/projects/environments/sec_download/lib/python3.5/site-packages/wtforms/form.py", line 152, in validate
    if not field.validate(self, extra):
  File "/home/prm/projects/environments/sec_download/lib/python3.5/site-packages/wtforms/fields/core.py", line 206, in validate
    stop_validation = self._run_validation_chain(form, chain)
  File "/home/prm/projects/environments/sec_download/lib/python3.5/site-packages/wtforms/fields/core.py", line 226, in _run_validation_chain
    validator(form, self)
  File "/home/prm/projects/environments/sec_download/lib/python3.5/site-packages/wtforms/validators.py", line 134, in __call__
    if data is None or (self.min is not None and data < self.min) or \
TypeError: unorderable types: str() < int()
```

I am expecting some JSON output to be thrown back at my browser. The error seems to happen only when I am including the form.validate snippet. Upon commenting that snippet the code seems to be running.

Comment: it seems it has problem because `data` is string instead of integer. You have to convert string to integer and put it back to form before validation.